# Flask and JS: Unable to Submit Form

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm having a issue submitting my form. I'm trying to a make a multi-step form with Flask and bit of JS. The basic HTML structure of the form is:

```html
   <form id="regForm" action="{{ url_for("index")}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     
    <div class="tab"> <!--Some fields--> </div>
    <div class="tab"> <!--Some fields--> </div>
    <div class="tab"> <!--Some fields--> </div>
    <div class="tab"> <!--Some fields--> </div>
   
   <!--Buttons to change tabs-->
  <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
```

The `nextPrev()` functions are in a file called `scripts.js`. This is directly from a W3 schools example. It is as follows:

```js
  var currentTab = 0; 
    showTab(currentTab);
    
    function showTab(n) {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      x[n].style.display = "block";
      if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
      }
      if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
      }
      fixStepIndicator(n)
    }
    
    function nextPrev(n) {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
      x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
      currentTab = currentTab + n;
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
      }
      showTab(currentTab);
    }
```

The `document.getElementById("regForm").submit();` line should be submitting the form, since I see the button text changing to 'Submit' on the last slide. This isn't submitting it to my app though. The app looks for a POST request to `/` .

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
import os

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)   
    assets._named_bundles = {}
    register_extensions(app)
      
    @app.route("/", methods =["GET", "POST"])
    def index():
       
        if request.method == "POST":
            # Do a bunch of stuff

        return render_template("index.html")
```

Why is this not sending a request to my Python script?

The above code is minimal, I've uploaded a [gist with the full code for Flask, JS, HTML](https://gist.github.com/thedivtagguy/1770e2c0335406b2065b815526643e15).

I've created a codesandbox with my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-bogdan-xvekm?file=/public/index.html), you can also view the form itself [here](https://xvekm.sse.codesandbox.io).

Answer (score 0):

Have you added csrf_protection in your app?

If you did, Then do csrf.protection.exempt()

Comment: No, I have not added this as far as I know. You can see the minimal script [here](https://gist.github.com/thedivtagguy/1770e2c0335406b2065b815526643e15#file-app-py)

Comment: Did you add the csrf_protection extension, in register_extensions function ??

Comment: [I don't think so...?](https://pastebin.com/ZaQPQBqw)

Comment: Can you please share the whole register_extensions function

Comment: That is the whole file.

Comment: # other extensions -> This

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234398/discussion-between-hridaya-agrawal-and-aman).